# Pass a text from one component to another component in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Below is my `landing-HTML` page

```
<div class="container">

  <div>
    <mat-radio-group class="selected-type" [(ngModel)]="selectedType" (change)="radioChange()">
      <p class="question">Which movie report would you like to see ?</p>
      <mat-radio-button id="movie-a" class="Movie-type" [value]="MovieType.HORROR">Horror</mat-radio-button>
      <mat-radio-button id="movie-b" class="Movie-type" [value]="MovieType.ROMANTIC">Romantic</mat-radio-button>

    </mat-radio-group>
  </div>

    <movie-report *ngIf="showMovieReport"></movie-report>

</div>
```

This `<movie-report>` is a different component and has its own `component.ts` which makes `REST Call` and give some data.

I wanted to pass the `MovieType` data to `MovieReport` component. How to do it ?

Comment: Better way use subject of rxjs or user HTML reference variable #variable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `@Input` to do so like below -

```
<movie-report [type]='MovieType' *ngIf="showMovieReport"></movie-report>
```

and In order to get this in the component `movie-report` you need to use `@Input`

```
export class MovieReportComponent {
  @Input('type') type: string;
  // You will get Input Data in ngOnInit life cycle hook of Angular component
}
```

For more details refer here -

- https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#pass-data-from-parent-to-child-with-input-binding

Comment: Hi - I tried and it is not working for me `<movie-report [type]='MovieType' *ngIf="showMovieReport"></movie-report>` and in `MovieReportLandingComponent` i set the value of `movieType` this way `this.movieType= this.selectedMovieType.toString()`

Comment: while click of the radio button, i will change the value of `showMovieReport` to `true` and am setting the value of `movieType` and then it loads the `MovieComponent` but the `movieType` is not getting passed

Comment: @Arun can you create stackblitz of the same what you exactly want

Comment: First time when i click the `radio-button` the value is not getting passed.. whereas it works after my second click ...

Comment: Probably you need to give same name to both radios

Comment: It worked successfully.... I was using the variable within Child-Component’s constructor, rather using it in ngOninit

Comment: @Arun, Ah yes, Even I updated the answer with important point

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send the selected movie type instead of passing 'MovieType' pass 'selectedType' as input param.Check whether selected value is empty or not.

```
<ng-container *ngIf='selectedType'>
    <movie-report [type]='selectedType' *ngIf="showMovieReport"></movie-report>
</ng-container>
```

In movie-report component

```
export class MovieReportComponent {
  @Input('type') type: string;
}
```

Comment: First time when i click the `radio-button` the value is not getting passed.. whereas it works after my second click ...

Comment: I had updated my code above.Please check if it help you.